# maven import file from same package

Tags: java, maven-3

I'm new to maven, and this is the simplest possible thing that anyone would want to do.

I have a test.java file in com.Myjava

I have a best.java file in com.MyJava

I want to import test.java into best.java.

When I add the import statement to best.java, and run mvn compile, I get duplicate class exception.

Thanks,
Richard Madson

Comment: please show the code with the class definitions. What are the names of the classes you define? One should be test, one should be best.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out,
I had forgotten to add the package name to one of the two files.
FacePalm!!!